# How to add item to list stored in sharedPreferences?

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to store list of string in local storage using `sharedPreferences`
When I lunch my app for the first time repository return `null` as it should.
When i tried to write any new item to my storage and then read it, function

> getSearchHistoryItems()

doesn't return any data. Is something wrong with my function to write
new items?

```
interface LocalPreferencesRepository {
    fun getSearchHistoryItems(): List<String>?
    fun addSearchHistoryItem(item: String)
}

class LocalPreferencesRepositoryImpl(
    private val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
) : LocalPreferencesRepository {

    override fun getSearchHistoryItems(): List<String>? {
        return Gson().fromJson(
            sharedPreferences.getString(PREF_SEARCH_HISTORY, null),
            object : TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {}.type
        )
    }

    override fun addSearchHistoryItem(item: String) {
        val listToSave = listOf(item).plus(getSearchHistoryItems())
        val json = Gson().toJson(listToSave)
        with(sharedPreferences.edit()) { putString(PREF_SEARCH_HISTORY, json); commit() }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val PREF_SEARCH_HISTORY = "PREF_SEARCH_HISTORY"
    }
}
```

Edit:

```
override fun getSearchHistoryItems(): List<String>? =
        try {
            Gson().fromJson(
                sharedPreferences.getString(PREF_SEARCH_HISTORY, "").orEmpty(),
                object : TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {}.type
            )
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            null
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`listToSave` is a `List<Any>` because `List<String> + List<String>?` is going to use the overload of `plus` that adds the second argument as a single element instead of iterating it and adding all its items. Why not make `getSearchHistoryItems()` return a non-nullable List (return with `.orEmpty()`)?

Also, I think you are in danger of a crash when there is nothing currently stored in the SharedPreference. I don't use Gson much, but doesn't it throw an exception if you pass it an invalid Json String or null?

Also, a tip. There's a KTX extension function `SharedPreferences.edit` function that lets you pass a lambda where you can put the edits and not have to commit manually. A little bit cleaner to use. By default it internally uses `apply()` instead of `commit()` which is what you typically should be doing anyway. If you really need to guarantee there's a write before returning, you should be using coroutines or using Jetpack Datastore instead of SharedPreferences.

```
interface LocalPreferencesRepository {
    fun getSearchHistoryItems(): List<String>
    fun addSearchHistoryItem(item: String)
}

class LocalPreferencesRepositoryImpl(
    private val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
) : LocalPreferencesRepository {

    override fun getSearchHistoryItems(): List<String> {
        return Gson().fromJson(
            sharedPreferences.getString(PREF_SEARCH_HISTORY, ""),
            object : TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {}.type
        ).orEmpty()
    }

    override fun addSearchHistoryItem(item: String) {
        val listToSave = listOf(item).plus(getSearchHistoryItems())
        val json = Gson().toJson(listToSave)
        sharedPreferences.edit { putString(PREF_SEARCH_HISTORY, json) }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val PREF_SEARCH_HISTORY = "PREF_SEARCH_HISTORY"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice